# What is the purpose of the method attribute-target?

Tags: c#, attributes

In the C# specification (17.2) it indicates there are several attribute targets when specifying an attribute. This is common when you need to apply an attribute to something that doesn't often have a "real" place to specify an attribute. For example, the `return` target is used often in platform Invoke:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SomeWin32Method(); //Assume this is valid, has a DllImport, etc.
```

However I noticed that there are other attribute targets, like `method`:

```
[method: DllImport("somelib.dll")]
static extern bool SomeWin32Method();
```

Under what circumstances would I need to explicitly define the `method` attribute target (say to resolve ambiguity), or is it just there for the sake of completeness?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to specify the target in this case (located directly above a method, `method` is the default target), it's just there for completeness. Just like you don't need to specify `private` when adding members to a class, but many people do it anyway. And in many cases code generators like to be extra explicit about things.

Also, i think in cases like this, the additional specifier makes things a bit more clear:

```
[method: SomeAttr]
[return: SomeOtherAttr]
int SomeMethod() { return 0; }
```

Comment: Also, in the example `[method: SomeAttr] public event Action MyFieldLikeEvent;`, the `method:` target is not redundant. It means the attribute is to be applied on both auto-generated accessors (`add` and `remove`). The default would be to apply the attribute to the event itself.

Comment: I believe you mean you don't need to specify `internal`, which is the default access modifier for unspecified fields, etc.